# How to batch insert data so that a field of inserted data is the maximum value in the database plus one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test`  (
  `serial` bigint(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `device_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `algorithm_id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `platform_id` bigint(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`device_code`, `algorithm_id`, `platform_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

Where  `device_code`、`algorithm_id` and `platform_id` constitutes the primary key, while the `serial` field can be repeated.

Now, I hope that every time I insert a batch of data, the value of this batch of `serial` is the same, for example: 1, but when I insert a batch of data again, the value of this batch of `serial` is the value of the previous batch of `serial` plus one, that is: 2.

My insert statement looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO test 
(`serial`, `name`, `device_code`, `algorithm_id`, `platform_id`) 
VALUES 
(3, "test3", "code1", 4, 1), 
(3, "test3", "code2", 4, 1), 
(3, "test3", "code3", 4, 1), 
(3, "test3", "code4", 4, 1), 
(3, "test3", "code1", 4, 2), 
(3, "test3", "code2", 4, 2), 
(3, "test3", "code3", 4, 2), 
(3, "test3", "code4", 4, 2), 
(3, "test3", "code1", 4, 3), 
(3, "test3", "code2", 4, 3), 
(3, "test3", "code3", 4, 3), 
(3, "test3", "code4", 4, 3)
```

I thought it might be possible to query the maximum serial value in the database before inserting data, but I'm worried that in case of concurrency, the inserted `serial` may be wrong or cause SQL execution failure

Any suggestion will help me. By the way, I use MySQL, but the answer is not limited to this.

Comment: Can you show us your insert query and some sample output?

Comment: The Primary and Unique key are exactly the same?? Does it really matter that serial increments by one for device_code、algorithm_id and platform_id ? If not use auto_increment

Comment: Normally, serials have a relaxed requirement to allow gaps in values. If you need strictly sequential numbers, your batch insert should utilize a CTE (to get the current MAX serial) and then INSERT with mutiple VALUES.

Comment: @P.Salmon In fact, the increment may not be one, but I hope it increases gradually. I need serial to query all the data of this batch, just like a group serial number, which represents a batch of data.

Comment: Your inserts will fail most of the time with `duplicate key` errors, since you try to insert the same data multiple times in the columns of your primary key. And your unique index is obsolete, since its the same as the primary key. You can remove it.

Comment: @fancyPants Yes, Unique key did conflict with the primary key, which was a mistake that I didn't realize. It's been adjusted. But there were no errors in my insertion, and I don't understand how the error you're referring to could have occurred.

Comment: If you are the only user possessing the INSERT privilege, then the concurrency problem does not pose a threat. You can get the max serial first and set the `serial` value before your batch insertion commences. But if other users are also entitled to INSERT privilege, how can you guarantee they do not use the same `serial` values which are already used in your previous batch insertion. And if they are free to use whatever `serial` values they want, does it circumvent your original intention of using the `serial` value as a reference of your batch inserting actions.